# Did Visual Studio 2008 Support SQL Reporting services 2008

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I need to send mail via data extension I am having Visual Studio 2008. I am migrating from Visual Studio 2005.

Will it possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this http://sqlcat.com/technicalnotes/archive/2008/07/09/scaling-up-reporting-services-2008-vs-reporting-services-2005-lessons-learned.aspx